# Ruby on Rails Create new Record with Values / Variables from a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, activerecord, actioncontroller

i´m using RoR 3.2.9.
Thanks to the help here, i managed to get something done!
Now i am trying to create a new record from a button_to in a view:

```
<%= button_to "Do IT", :controller => :apos, 
                           :method => :match %>
```

Controller looks like this:

```
class AposController < ApplicationController

...

def new
-> standard
end

def create
-> standard
end

def match
    #@apo = Apo.new(:auftrnr => $aktuelleID, :artikelnummer => @artikel.artikelnummer, :beschreibung => @artikel.name, :menge => 0)
    #@apo = Apo.new(:auftrnr => 2)
    @user = User.new do |apo|
        apo.auftrnr = 1
        apo.artikelnummer = 1
    end
    @apo.save
  end
end
```

The creation of the new record worked.
But the first thing that is strange, that i receive the message:

*Apo was successfully created.*

...which is defined in the Controller´s create method (i didn´t call it, did i?)
Well, and then the record is created empty although i tried to create it with some values (tried the 3 possibilities u can see above so i think it´s not an ActiveRecord Syntax Error)

*Apo was successfully created.
Auftragsnummer: 15

Zahlungsart:

Bankverbindung:

Lieferadresse:

Start shopping

Edit | Back*

(the '15' is the ID of this Class)

I was expecting some contents in this newly created record :-(

I tried this with defining methods in other controllers as well with the same results. 
Any idea what i am doing wrong again??

Thaaaanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
:controller => :apos, :method => :match
```

to

```
:controller => :apos, :action=> :match
```

and make sure you save the actual record - you currently save the `@apo` variable while building the record as `@user`

Comment: Oh, sorry for this stupid mistake. I fixed the code in the method but posted the old one :-( ... but anyway, the effects are the same. and actually i don´t want to use an "action" cause as far as i understood this means rendering a view... i just want to create a record without doing anything else :-) To do this, do i have to create methods in a class which is not a controller or how can i do this? thanks

Comment: and anyway, any idea, why the Controller´s create method is activated without calling it? is this something like rails standard?

Comment: "i just want to create a record without doing anything else" - when a browser makes a request, it must receive a response that it can act upon.  Rails therefore requires you to send _something_ back to the browser.  You can have rails issue a redirect to the same page instead of rendering a view, or you can make the request as an ajax request and have the browser ignore whatever response you send back (which can be as simple as 'success').  But no response at all is not an option.

Comment: "why the Controller´s create method is activated without calling it?" - well you actually _are_ calling it due to RESTful standards.  That is, you are sending a POST request (submit default) to the form action url built from the unpersisted record, which happens to the be right combination for rails to interpret as routing to the 'create' action.  You may want to read up about rails routing and RESTful resources...

Comment: Please post the HTML that is generated for the 'button_to' code.  Also is this button inside a form? If so, move it out of the form.

Comment: <h1>Folgenden Artikel hinzugefuegen?</h1>

<p>
  <b>Auftrag:</b> <%= $aktuelleID %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Artikelnummer:</b>
  <%= artikel.artikelnummer %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Artikelnummer:</b>
  <%= @artikel.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Verfuegbare Menge:</b>
  <%= artikel.bestand %>
</p>

<%= form_for(@artikel) do |f| %>

 <div class="field">
 <b>Gewuenschte Menge?</b>
    <br />
    <%= f.number_field :kundenbestmenge %>
  </div>
<% end %>  

<%= link_to "New Apos", new_apo_path %><br>

<br>
<%= button_to "Ja", :controller => :apos, 
                           :action => :match %>

Comment: Ok, i now solved it by sticking to RESTful actions. I am now calling :controller => :apos, :action => :match and am rendering the match.html.erb ... i think slowly i´m getting into it. Thanks @all for your help here!